# Why cant set the value of the second and the third selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 selection box. The second selection box depends on the option in the first selection box. And the third selection box depends on the the option in the second selection box. But in the code below I only write one selection box for one option. The problem is if I get data from database, I can't set the value of the second and the third selection box. In the code below I set the vaIue in some variables.

I've tried using this:

```
$("#k1").val(icd);
$("#"+icd).show();
$("#"+icd).val(icd1);

console.log($("#"+icd).val());

if (icd2 != "") {
   $("#"+icd1).show();
   $("#"+icd1).val(icd2);
}
```

but nothing happened.

Here's the complete code:

```js
var icd = "K02";
var icd1 = "K02-4";
var icd2 = "Melanodontoclasia";

$("#k1").val(icd);
$("#" + icd).show();
$("#" + icd).val(icd1);
if (icd2 != "") {
  $("#" + icd1).show();
  $("#" + icd1).val(icd2);
}

$("#k1").change(function() {
  correspondingID = $(this).find(":selected").val()
  console.log("1" + correspondingID);
  $(".style-sub-1").hide();
  $("#" + correspondingID).show();
  $("#" + correspondingID).change(function() {
    correspondingID2 = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    console.log("2" + correspondingID2);
    $(".style-sub-2").hide();
    $("#" + correspondingID2).show();
    var nyari = $('div').find("#" + correspondingID2);
    //var cari = find($("#"+correspondingID2));
    console.log(nyari.length);
    if (nyari.length == 0) {
      correspondingID3 = "";
    } else {
      $("#" + correspondingID2).change(function() {
        correspondingID3 = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        console.log("3" + correspondingID3);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select size="1" id="k1" class="form-control" type="select" name="kode_icd" value="-Select Your Rank-">
    <option disabled selected value>pilih</option> 
    <option value="K00">K00 Disorders of tooth development and eruption</option>
    <option value="K01">K01 Embedded and impacted teeth</option>
    <option value="K02">K02 Dental caries</option>
    <option value="K03">K03 Other diseases of hard tissues of teeth</option>
    <option value="K04">K04 Diseases of pulp and periapical tissues</option>
    <option value="K05">K05 Gingivitis and periodontal diseases</option>
    <option value="K06">K06 Other disorders of gingiva and edentulous alveolar ridge</option>
    <option value="K07">K07 Dentofacial anomalies [including malocclusion]</option>
    <option value="K08">K08 Other disorders of teeth and supporting structures</option>
    <option value="K09">K09 Cysts of oral region, not elsewhere classified</option>
    <option value="K10">K10 Other diseases of jaws</option>
    <option value="K11">K11 Diseases of salivary glands</option>
    <option value="K12">K12 Stomatitis and related lesions</option>
    <option value="K13">K13 Other diseases of lip and oral mucosa</option>
    <option value="K14">K14 Diseases of tongue</option>
</select>

<div id="K02" class="style-sub-1" style="display: none;" name="stylesub1">
  <label> </label>
  <select id="K02" name="kode_icd1" class="form-control">
        <option disabled selected value>pilih</option>  
        <option value="K02-0">K02.0 Caries limited to enamel</option>
        <option value="K02-1">K02.1 Caries of dentine</option>
        <option value="K02-2">K02.2 Caries of cementum</option>
        <option value="K02-3">K02.3 Arrested dental caries</option>
        <option value="K02-4">K02.4 Odontoclasia</option>
        <option value="K02-5">K02.5 Other dental caries</option>
        <option value="K02-6">K02.6 Dental caries, unspecified</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="K02-0" class="style-sub-2" style="display: none;" name="stylesub1">
  <label> </label>
  <select id="k02-0" name="kode_icd2" class="form-control">
        <option disabled selected value>pilih</option>  
        <option value="White spot lesions [initial caries]">White spot lesions [initial caries]</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="K02-4" class="style-sub-2" style="display: none;" name="stylesub1">
  <label> </label>
  <select id="k02-4" name="kode_icd2" class="form-control">
        <option disabled selected value>pilih</option>  
        <option value="Infantile melanodontia">Infantile melanodontia</option>
        <option value="Melanodontoclasia">Melanodontoclasia</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You could copy the fiddle code over and create a snippet right here.

Comment: change `correspondingID2 = $(this).find(":selected").val();` to `var correspondingID2 = $(this).find(":selected").attr('id');`

Comment: @SharmilaJesupaul still can't select the value

Comment: right now you have only value for K02 only so if you select **<option value="K02">K02 Dental caries</option>** , you will get dropdown for second select box

Comment: @ChiragPatel I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used id "K02" on div as well on select, which is causing the issue. Because when you try to select DOM element using id the first element from top having that id is returned.

Here is updated code.

```
<select size="1" id="k1" class="form-control" type="select" name="kode_icd" value="-Select Your Rank-">
                      <option disabled selected value>pilih</option>  
                      <option value="K00">K00 Disorders of tooth development and eruption</option>
                      <option value="K01">K01 Embedded and impacted teeth</option>
                      <option value="K02">K02 Dental caries</option>
                      <option value="K03">K03 Other diseases of hard tissues of teeth</option>
                      <option value="K04">K04 Diseases of pulp and periapical tissues</option>
                      <option value="K05">K05 Gingivitis and periodontal diseases</option>
                      <option value="K06">K06 Other disorders of gingiva and edentulous alveolar ridge</option>
                      <option value="K07">K07 Dentofacial anomalies [including malocclusion]</option>
                      <option value="K08">K08 Other disorders of teeth and supporting structures</option>
                      <option value="K09">K09 Cysts of oral region, not elsewhere classified</option>
                      <option value="K10">K10 Other diseases of jaws</option>
                      <option value="K11">K11 Diseases of salivary glands</option>
                      <option value="K12">K12 Stomatitis and related lesions</option>
                      <option value="K13">K13 Other diseases of lip and oral mucosa</option>
                      <option value="K14">K14 Diseases of tongue</option>
                    </select>
<div  id = "K02" class="style-sub-1" style="display: none;" name="stylesub1">
  <label> </label>
  <select id="K02-select" name="kode_icd1" class="form-control">
                    <option disabled selected value>pilih</option>  
                    <option value="K02-0">K02.0 Caries limited to enamel</option>
                    <option value="K02-1">K02.1 Caries of dentine</option>
                    <option value="K02-2">K02.2 Caries of cementum</option>
                    <option value="K02-3">K02.3 Arrested dental caries</option>
                    <option value="K02-4">K02.4 Odontoclasia</option>
                    <option value="K02-5">K02.5 Other dental caries</option>
                    <option value="K02-6">K02.6 Dental caries, unspecified</option>
                  </select>
</div>
<div id="K02-0" class="style-sub-2" style="display: none;" name="stylesub1">
  <label> </label>
  <select id="k02-0" name="kode_icd2" class="form-control">
                    <option disabled selected value>pilih</option>  
                    <option value="White spot lesions [initial caries]">White spot lesions [initial caries]</option>
                  </select>
</div>
<div id="K02-4" class="style-sub-2" style="display: none;" name="stylesub1">
  <label> </label>
  <select id="k02-4" name="kode_icd2" class="form-control">
                    <option disabled selected value>pilih</option>  
                    <option value="Infantile melanodontia">Infantile melanodontia</option>
                    <option value="Melanodontoclasia">Melanodontoclasia</option>
                  </select>
</div>
```

JavaScript as follow: 
Note: I have document.ready as well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var icd = "K02";
var icdS = "K02-select";
var icd1 = "K02-4";
var icd2 = "Melanodontoclasia";

$("#k1").val(icd);
$("#" + icd).show();
$("#" + icdS).val(icd1);
if (icd2 != "") {
    $("#" + icd1).show();
    $("#" + icd1).val(icd2);

}

$("#k1").change(function () {
    correspondingID = $(this).find(":selected").val()
    console.log("1" + correspondingID);
    $(".style-sub-1").hide();
    $("#" + correspondingID).show();
    $("#" + correspondingID).change(function () {
        correspondingID2 = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        console.log("2" + correspondingID2);
        $(".style-sub-2").hide();
        $("#" + correspondingID2).show();
        var nyari = $('div').find("#" + correspondingID2);
        //var cari = find($("#"+correspondingID2));
        console.log(nyari.length);
        if (nyari.length == 0) {
            correspondingID3 = "";
        } else {
            $("#" + correspondingID2).change(function () {
                correspondingID3 = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                console.log("3" + correspondingID3);
            });

        }

    });
});
});
```